# Turn int to char C

Tags: c, char, int

I am trying to turn int like `72, 101, 108` to `'72', '101', '108'`.

The original program is that I am read the string `"Hello\n"` for example, then get the ASCII values of each character, then put those int into a char array.

I tried:

```
int a = 72;
char b = (char)a;
```

But this will convert the int from ASCII back to the character.

I also tried:

```
int a = 72;
char b = a + '0';
```

But this just does not work at all.

This is what I have:

```
char buff[128];
strcpy(buff, "Hello\n");

char tmp[128];
bzero(tmp, 128); // initialize array

int n = 0;
while(buff[n] != '\n') {
   int ascii = (int)buff[n];
   en[n] = (char)ascii; // RIGHT HERE
   n++;
}
strcat(tmp, "\n");

fprintf(stdout,"%s", tmp);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since when did these `'72', '101', '108'` become chars? Char values are stored in 1 byte.

You can use [sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/sprintf) or [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/snprintf). To convert the integers to char arrays.

```
int c = 4;
char tin [Some_Length];
sprintf(tin , "%d", c);
```

Or

```
snprintf(tin , Some_Length, "%d", c);
```